# Javascript / Php : set textarea value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following script, which returns 2 values from my database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?
    $link=new mysqli($serveur,$login,$pass,$base);
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

    $r=mysqli_query($link, "select sujet,corps from mail where type='Création_rationnaire'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    ?>
        document.getElementById("sujet").value="<? echo $row[sujet];?>";
        document.getElementById("te").value="<? echo $row[corps];?>";
    <? }mysqli_close($link); ?>
});
```

Here are my 2 forms, one is a classic Input, the other is a textarea.

```
<input id='sujet' class="form-field">
<textarea id="te" class="textarea" rows="9" cols="70"></textarea>
```

The problem is : my SQL request works in MySQL, but when "corps" is echoed as above, nothing appears in the Inputs, like the script was crashing... Only "sujet" can be echoed successfully. So... why, just why ? Thanks in advance for whoever helps me.

EDIT : all I can echo in the "te" textbox is a single string like this : `echo 'something';`... but nothing else works...

Comment: if you have the plain html, why don't you just `<input id='sujet' class="form-field" value="<?php echo $row['sujet']; ?>">` Sounds easier, no? You are asking js to perform a plain parse action that can be done through php directly..

Comment: The way you're mixing client- and server-side language hurts my eyes. There's no need for that blend if you're not doing ajax (async requests).

Comment: Are your short tags enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by inserting the values directly into the plain html forms. I usually use this javascript function because I have tons of forms to fill in my program, and it never failed until now... So my function above was good, but we still don't know why it failed in this particular case...

Problem solved anyways... thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("sujet").value="<? echo $row['sujet'];?>";
document.getElementById("te").text="<? echo $row['corps'];?>";
```

or if you use jquery

```
var message = <?php echo $row['corps']; ?>;
$("#te").val(message);
```

Textarea does not have a value but it does have text.

in an input box you would have `<input type="text" value="example" />` and in a text area the value is inside the element like so

`<textarea>example</textarea>`

A other way is to use innerHtml (javascript) or html (jquery) .
But note that html tags will be display with one of these options

Comment: @AlphaGrisby then try with html or innerhtml

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("te").innerHTML="<? echo $row['corps'];?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea>` doesn't have value property. Since you are using jQuery to bind document ready, you can use jQuery to set the value.

```
$("#sujet").val("<? echo $row[sujet];?>");
$("#te").html("<? echo $row[corps];?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of $row[corps]? Is it empty string? Does it contain double quote, or newline characters? If it contains any of them, it will break your javascript source code. What does javascript source code look like when you check source code inside the browser?